# dictionary inside dictionary sorting

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, lambda

**this is the dict i need to sort it by "error" value**

```
{'mdouglas': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 3}, 'noel': {'INFO': 6, 'ERROR': 3}, 'breee': {'INFO': 1, 'ERROR': 5}, 'ac': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 2}, 'blossom': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 6}, 'rr.robinson': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 1}, 'mcintosh': {'INFO': 4, 'ERROR': 3}, 'jackowens': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 4}, 'oren': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 7}, 'xlg': {'INFO': 0, 'ERROR': 4}, 'ahmed.miller': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 4}, 'bpacheco': {'INFO': 0, 'ERROR': 2}, 'enim.non': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 3}, 'flavia': {'INFO': 0, 'ERROR': 5}, 'sri': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 2}, 'nonummy': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 3}, 'britanni': {'INFO': 1, 'ERROR': 1}, 'montanap': {'INFO': 0, 'ERROR': 4}, 'mai.hendrix': {'INFO': 0, 'ERROR': 3}, 'kirknixon': {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 1}}
```

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: That's a dictionary, not a list

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! I recommend looking at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As posed, there's not enough info here to help. There is no list in your question and there are no tuples. You also don't tell us what your inputs are, what your desired output is, and how you've tried to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job,

```
errors = [(key, data[key]["ERROR"]) for key in data.keys()] #data here is the dictionary
snorted_keys = sorted(errors, key = lambda item:item[-1])
snorted_dict = list(map(lambda item:(item[0], data[item[0]]), snorted_keys))
```

Output -

```
[('rr.robinson', {'ERROR': 1, 'INFO': 2}),
 ('britanni', {'ERROR': 1, 'INFO': 1}),
 ('kirknixon', {'ERROR': 1, 'INFO': 2}),
 ('ac', {'ERROR': 2, 'INFO': 2}),
 ('bpacheco', {'ERROR': 2, 'INFO': 0}),
 ('sri', {'ERROR': 2, 'INFO': 2}),
 ('mdouglas', {'ERROR': 3, 'INFO': 2}),
 ('noel', {'ERROR': 3, 'INFO': 6}),
 ('mcintosh', {'ERROR': 3, 'INFO': 4}),
 ('enim.non', {'ERROR': 3, 'INFO': 2}),
 ('nonummy', {'ERROR': 3, 'INFO': 2}),
 ('mai.hendrix', {'ERROR': 3, 'INFO': 0}),
 ('jackowens', {'ERROR': 4, 'INFO': 2}),
 ('xlg', {'ERROR': 4, 'INFO': 0}),
 ('ahmed.miller', {'ERROR': 4, 'INFO': 2}),
 ('montanap', {'ERROR': 4, 'INFO': 0}),
 ('breee', {'ERROR': 5, 'INFO': 1}),
 ('flavia', {'ERROR': 5, 'INFO': 0}),
 ('blossom', {'ERROR': 6, 'INFO': 2}),
 ('oren', {'ERROR': 7, 'INFO': 2})]
```

Comment: I gotta ask: "snorted"?

Comment: sorry i was got the result as list

Comment: thanks i got what i want but is there one line method ?[('oren', {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 7}), ('blossom', {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 6}), ('breee', {'INFO': 1, 'ERROR': 5}), ('flavia', {'INFO': 0, 'ERROR': 5}), ('jackowens', {'INFO': 2, 'ERROR': 4}), ('xlg', {'INFO': 0, 'ERROR': 4}),

Comment: @ShadowRanger My bad, must have been a typo. But imma let it be there.

Comment: this didnt work g= sorted(per_user.items(), key = lambda x: (x[1]["ERROR"]),reverse=True)

Comment: @abedalswaity7 Can you update the question itself for better clarity?